# Gaussian mixture model - mode finding

Tags: statistics

I'm doing some research, and I stuck at finding mode for gaussian mixture model. I have set of $3D$ points. For each pair of points, I need to calculate following:

$\pi_{ij}$ - probability that points $p_i$ and $p_j$ are located on the same circular object.

$\mathcal{N}(\theta;\mu_{ij},\sigma_{ij}^2I)$ - probability of both points lying on the boundary of the same circular object
whose center and radius are represented by $\theta(x,y,z)$. I know the values of $\pi_{ij}$, $\mu_{ij}$ and $\sigma_{ij}^2I$, and coordinates of points $p_i$ and $p_j$.

GMM is defined as:

$\sum_i\sum_j\pi_{ij}\mathcal{N}(\theta;\mu_{ij},\sigma_{ij}^2I)$.

What is the best way to find mode?

Answer (score 0):

To find the modes of Gaussian mixture using an iterative process, you can use Meanshift:
See http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00687 for a detailed review.